# Error when adding edges to network graph: 'v_of_edge'

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to create a network graph in NetworkX based on a defeaultdict which contains nodes and edges. When I try to add the edges, I get the following error message:

> add_edge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v_of_edge'

My code is as follows:

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
      "b" : ["c", "e"],
      "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
      "d" : ["c"],
      "e" : ["c", "b"],
      "f" : []
    } 

G = nx.Graph()

for k,v in graph.items():

    G.add_node(k)
    G.add_edge(*v)
nx.draw()
plt.show()
```

I know that `add_edge` takes `(u,v)` argument, where I suppose that `u` is node and `v` is the edges, so instead I tried:

```
G.add_edge(k,v)
```

But that resulted in a new error message saying:

> unhashable type: 'list'

I don't know how to proceed, but it leaves me at least one question.
In the second approach, should I somehow access each edge for a given node individually?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation of add_edge (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html)? Does it help?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann It made me think that I had to loop through each element in the associated list for each node, as Yilun suggested below.
Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: When you get an error like this suggesting that you're sending the wrong data type to a function, the first thing you should do is print that argument before the function call.  Often that's enough to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `v` is a list in your graph structure definition. The following code will make it work:

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
      "b" : ["c", "e"],
      "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
      "d" : ["c"],
      "e" : ["c", "b"],
      "f" : []
    } 

G = nx.Graph()

for k,v in graph.items():
    for vv in v:
        G.add_edge(k,vv)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Based on your definition, you are supposed to loop through the list associated with each node to define the edge.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix-up to your code that will make it work:

```
import networkx as nx
graph = {'a': ['c'], 'b': ['c', 'e'], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], 'd': ['c'], 'e': ['c', 'b'], 'f': []}

G = nx.Graph()

for k,v in graph.items():
    G.add_node(k)
    for i in v:
        G.add_edge(k, i)

nx.draw(G)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

As you can see, the main issue is that you need to properly add each edge. Since your `v` are lists, you must go item by item in that list to add the edge.

Comment: Thank you Yamilla! I decided to accept Yilun answer above as he posted the solution first and your solutions essentially suggest the same.

Comment: AttributeError: 'MultiDiGraph' object has no attribute 'items'